# Excel hyperlink

Tags: excel, email, hyperlink

I am trying to build a formula that will show a link in a cell and when clicked, it will open an email and populate the email recipient, subject and body fields with data from other cells.

Here's what doesn't work so far,

```
=HYPERLINK("mailto:"&J2&"?subject="&$E$2&"&cc=""&body="&$O$2,"Send Email")
```

What would be REALLY great is to add an IF to the formula so that **if** the subject (column E) is one thing (A), it would reference subject and body A cells and if it was another thing (B) it would reference subject and body B cells.

The error I get is #VALUE.

I'm looking for the simplest method, avoiding VBA if I can, but I'll give it a whirl if I need to.

Your help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try on below formula.

```
=HYPERLINK("mailto:" & J2 & "?subject="& E2 & "&body=" & IF(E2="A",A1,IF(E2="B",A2,"")), "Send mail")
```

[image]

Comment: So close! I edited your formula and it's doing everything except posting the text in O2 into the body. I haven't even tried to make 'B' work yet, just trying to get 'A' to work first. THANKS for replying btw.

Comment: =HYPERLINK("mailto:" & J2 & "?subject="& E2 & "&body=" & IF(E2="LOW BATT",O2,IF(E2="OFFLINE",N2,"")), "Send mail")

Comment: So, did it finally work after modification or still need help. If problem is solved then you can tick mark the answer so that other visitor can know the thread is solved.

Comment: I think that the O2 cell problem is that it is multi-line text for the body of the email. When I pointed to N2 which only has a single line of text, it worked.

Comment: I just need to figure out a way to get it to grab O2 (multi-line text) for the email body. Everything else seems to work fine. So yes, I still need some help if you don't mind.

Comment: @NormRobichaud Then can try `=HYPERLINK("mailto:" & J2 & "?subject="& E2 & "&body=" & SUBSTITUTE(IF(E2="A",A1,IF(E2="B",A2,"")),CHAR(10),"%0d%0a"), "Send mail")` Here Char(10) means line break between cell texts which will be replaced by `%0d%0a`. And `%0d%0a` means new line for outlook body texts.

Comment: =HYPERLINK("mailto:" & J2 & "?subject="& E2 & "&body=" & IF(E2="LOW BATT",$O$2,IF(E2="OFFLINE",$O$3,"")), "Send mail")

If E2 = LOW BATT, then the cell shows the error '#VALUE', if E2 does not = LOW BATT it shows 'Send mail' and clicking on it generates an email with the email address and subject working correctly, but no body.

Comment: Can you put a screenshot what you have in O2 cell?

Comment: See your first answer, click on 'enter image description here'.